# python sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture suspicious results

Tags: python

I'm using GaussianMixture to model a two component mixture of gaussian distributions and the results don't look optimal. I thought I could do better manual and gave it a go, so I'm wondering why the results of GaussianMixture aren't as good as I can do just by eye? Am I missing some option for iterating to an optimal solution?

```
nc = 2
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=nc).fit(x.reshape(-1,1))
gSum = 0
for i in range(nc):
    gSum = gSum + gmm.weights_[i]*stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x_axis, gmm.means_[i],gmm.covariances_[i])
    plt.plot(x_axis,gmm.weights_[i]*stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x_axis, gmm.means_[i],gmm.covariances_[i]))
    
plt.plot(x_axis, gSum)
plt.hist(x,bins='auto',density=1)
plt.show()
```

[Output showing histogram of data and gaussians from GaussianMixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlgL2.png)

as an example of how I thought I could do better, here are two gaussians that more closely match the histogram:

```
base = np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x),num = 1000)
g = stats.norm.pdf(base, 0.167,0.012)
f = stats.norm.pdf(base, 0.136,0.0045)

a = 0.92
b = 1-a
plt.plot(base,a*g)
plt.plot(base,b*f)
plt.plot(base,a*g+b*f)
plt.hist(x,bins='auto',density=1)
plt.show()
```

[manually solved gaussian mixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqwY6.png)

Any tips on how to get GuassianMixture to do better?

Comment: Remember that GMMs are fitted to data by the EM algorithm, which can always get stuck in local minima. Hence, the most likely explanation to me is that you got such a local minima. Try increasing `n_init` and `max_iter`.